# How to Set up Google Analytics / google Tag Manager for Payment referral sites

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have just changed my sites payment gateway from embedded ( inside my site ) to redirect to the payment gateway site.

The problem now is that all my conversions are coming from the bank secure site - and there are a LOT of them it's not just one URL.  If it was just one URL I could put that URL into the referral exclusion list. but I don't think that is the correct way to do this.

What is the correct way to implement a payment that goes off to another site and then returns so that it registers the correct starting point ( in most cases adwords )

thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Referral Exclusion list by entering the domain to exclude, not the entire URL. If there are several third levels of the same domain you have to enter the main domain.

Comment: Sorry - there must be another way to do it.  there are a lot of different sites to exclude as it comes back directly from a secure bank site ( at least 20 so far )

Comment: How do you think Google knows which domains you want to exclude and which you don't? The referral exclusion list is just for that... You can try to do this programmatically instead of from the interface, but you will still have to define a list to exclude.

Comment: I guess I just found the exact question somewhere else https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/14755905?hl=en  not sure if the utm_nooverride=1 is still a valid option

Comment: In Universal Analytics and for the active session the utm_nooverride works: https://www.analyticstraps.com/utm_nooverride-in-universal-analytics-funziona-ancora/ if you can add this parameter in backlink from payment gateway, should be a solution